# jssor-how to stop sliders at the lastslide automatically when autoplay is on?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I used jssor plugin for sliders. I have added three slides. I want to end the slideshow at the last slide. could anyone help me in finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options = {
            $AutoPlay: true,
            $DragOrientation: 3                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        function OnSliderPark(slideIndex, fromIndex)
        {
            if (slideIndex == 2)
                jssor_slider1.$Pause();
        }

        jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, OnSliderPark);
    });
</script>
```